# Service Stack POST-Request Body-Format / Transformation

Tags: json, rest, post, servicestack

iam using a RequestClass with the Route anotation to call a Json-Client POST method.
Now, while the paramters are structured like this

```
public class GetTicketRequest: IReturn<JsonObject>
{
    public string CartId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string PriceId {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The BackendAPI needs them to be nesten in "data" in the json request, so more like

```
{
   "data":[
   {"cartid":123,
   "priceId":11}]
}
```

Is there any way to transfrom the request object for the body before calling

```
JsonServiceClient _restClient = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
JsonObject oneResponse = _restClient.Post(options);
```

Comment: Found maybe a idea how to solve this https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Extras/blob/master/doc/UsageExamples/UsingRestAndJson.cs#L34 ... but not really sure how to apply this

Comment: I have updated my answer, as I had missed the `string` conversion to `int`. It should now provide a simple and complete solution for manipulating your DTOs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is useful where many DTOs require to be wrapped & converted, and is highly reusable, with no changes to your existing DTOs.

You can convert the requests of the `JsonServiceClient` by overriding the methods that handle preparing the requests for sending. Which means implementing your own extended `JsonServiceClient` *as given below*.

If you want to do this for all verbs then you override it's `Send<TResponse>` methods *(otherwise, if it's just for `POST` then uncomment the commented out code, and remove the Send methods)*.

```cs
public class MyJsonServiceClient : JsonServiceClient
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> DtoConverters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    public MyJsonServiceClient() {}
    public MyJsonServiceClient(string baseUri) : base(baseUri) {}
    public MyJsonServiceClient(string syncReplyBaseUri, string asyncOneWayBaseUri) : base(syncReplyBaseUri, asyncOneWayBaseUri) {}

    public override TResponse Send<TResponse>(object request)
    {
        return base.Send<TResponse>(ConvertRequest(request));
    }

    public override TResponse Send<TResponse>(string httpMethod, string relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, object request)
    {
        return base.Send<TResponse>(httpMethod, relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, ConvertRequest(request));
    }

    /*
    public override TResponse Post<TResponse>(string relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, object requestDto)
    {
        return base.Post(relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, ConvertRequest(requestDto));
    }
    */

    object ConvertRequest(object request)
    {
        Type dtoType = request.GetType();
        return (DtoConverters.ContainsKey(dtoType)) ? DtoConverters[dtoType](request) : request;
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

So given this DTO:

```cs
[Route("/test", "POST")]
public class TicketRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public string PriceId { get; set; }
}
```

You simply add the converter:

```cs
var client = new MyJsonServiceClient("http://localhost:9000");

// Simple converter for TicketRequest
client.DtoConverters.Add(typeof(TicketRequest), dto => {
    var d = (TicketRequest)dto;
    return new { 
        data = new { 
            CartId = d.CartId.ToInt(), 
            PriceId = d.PriceId.ToInt() 
        } 
    };
});

client.Post(new TicketRequest { CartId = "123", PriceId = "456" });
```

Comment: a really helpfull answer, thank you very much. eventhough my answer is the straight forward approach and you can solve it case by case, in 90% of all cases you approach will be far more elegant and usefull - in my particular case your approach is far superior. Thank you!

Comment: @emx Glad it was useful :) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue using a typed data property

```
public class GetTicketRequest: IReturn<JsonObject>
{
    public class TicketCreateData
    {            
        public int priceId {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public string CartId {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string PriceId {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public List<TicketCreateData> data {
        get {
            var list = new List<TicketCreateData>();
            list.Add(new TicketCreateData {
                priceId = this.PriceId.ToInt()
            });
            return list;
        }
        set {
            data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

To notes on this:

- if neede, use DataContract/DataMember(Name="") to rename fields or only do partial serializing
- Do *never* use structs for, like in this case, the data class - they are not serializeable at all
- in my spefici case data even needs to be an array, thats why i used the list